# How to remove backslashes from JSON PHP written file

Tags: php, json

My script is producing a JSON file that should be like:

```
[{"activeSheetIndex":0,"sheetCount":1,"tabStripRatio":0.5,"tabStripVisible":true,"tabEditable":true,"newTabVisible":true,"referenceStyle":0,
```

But is like:

```
{\"activeSheetIndex\":0,\"sheetCount\":1,\"tabStripRatio\":0.5,\"tabStripVisible\":true,\"tabEditable\":true,\"newTabVisible\":true,\"referenceStyle\":0,
```

How do I get rid of those backslashes?

I tried str_replace but it isn't working:

```
$myFile = $diretorio."/dados.json";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("não é possível abrir o ficheiro");

$stringData = $_POST['data'];
$stringData= str_replace('\\/', '', $stringData);   
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: What does `var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc());` output?

Comment: Try to do json_encode($_POST['data']) and see the result

Comment: PHP's `json_encode()` function generates a valid JSON string for the input data you give it. Don't try to change the JSON string after it's been generated; just fix the input data.

Comment: json_encode() is actually producing 3 backslashes instead of one

Comment: What does your dados.json look like?

Comment: The idea of backslash is to create a json compatible with any json parser, because you are using escape characters (double quotes ").

Comment: dados.json is the file being created. It looks like I describe it above.